# Selecting Areas for Sales Reps

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an application that is for sales reps. 
I'm trying to pull different institutions information based on 2 things

1. If they are a client
2. If they are in the state that the user (sales rep) is over.

So I want to show all the institutions that are clients in the current_user (sales reps) area. How can I do that?

Since I haven't done this before and I'm newer to rails I'm not sure how to do this.

Here are my models (I've shortened the code):

**User(Sales Rep)**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states, :through => :rep_areas
  has_many :institutions, :through => :company_reps
  has_many :rep_areas
  has_many :company_reps
end
```

**States**

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :rep_areas
  has_many :rep_areas
  has_many :institutions

  attr_accessible :code, :name
end
```

**Institutions**

```
class Institution < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company, :phone, :clientdate, :street, :city, :state_id, :zip, :source, :source2, :demodate1, :demodate2, :demodate3, :client, :prospect, :notcontacted
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :users, :through => :company_reps
  has_many :company_reps
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to proceed in this way:

```
states = current_user.states.to_a

# the following are all the Institution record in all the user's areas
inst_in_states = Institution.where(state_id: states)
# it will take an array and make an "IN" query

# the following are all the user's own clients, additionally on the states
# the user is in.
clients_in_states = current_user.institutions.where(state_id: states)
# as above, but additionally use the :company_reps join
```